Pine script involving 2 indicators and time
I'm new to pine script and I'd like to make a question if this is feasible or not.
I want an alert (later I want to send this to a trading bot) that activates on the following scenario:
IF

a. the last time stochastic RSI has crossed was in the up direction

AND

b. MACD had a dark green bar at that time (see a)

AND

c. MACD has a first red bar at the current time

THEN

give me an alert

Of course we can connect with any API that sends real time data and program all these in any language we use like php or server side javascript but I wonder if pine script can do things like that keeping values in time and compare with other values in current time.
Thanks for your help!

If you really want to store the values at the exact moment that your cross takes place, you can do it with a varip variable. However, this is complicated stuff and prone to repainting.
The problem with this is, you will only have access to this value as long as your chart is open and untouched (no re-execution of the script). However, your alerts should work fine.
If you want to evaluate your conditions when a bar closes and store them, you can do that with a var variable. This is an easier and safer approach.
